# How to get colon delimited values from a string in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string

```
$style = "font-color:#000;font-weight:bold;background-color:#fff";
```

I need only

```
font-color
font-weight
background-color
```

I have tried

```
preg_match_all('/(?<names>[a-z\-]+:)/', $style, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

it gives me following output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'font-color:' (length=11)
      1 => string 'font-weight:' (length=12)
      2 => string 'background-color:' (length=17)
  'names' => 
    array
      0 => string 'font-color:' (length=11)
      1 => string 'font-weight:' (length=12)
      2 => string 'background-color:' (length=17)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string 'font-color:' (length=11)
      1 => string 'font-weight:' (length=12)
      2 => string 'background-color:' (length=17)
```

There are three problems with this output
1. It is two or three dimensional array, I need one dimensional array.
2. It is repeating the information
3. It is appending ":" at the end of each element.

I need a single array like this

```
array
0 => 'font-color'
1 => 'font-weight'
2 => 'background-color'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out the colon:

```
$style = "font-color:#000;font-weight:bold;background-color:#fff";
preg_match_all('/(?<names>[a-z\-]+):/', $style, $matches);

var_dump($matches['names']);
```

Then use `$matches['names']`, since you named it, so you dont have redundant informations